# ngIf with routing

Tags: angular7, show-hide

I need help figuring out how to do this with Angular 7:

```
IF route = page, THEN SHOW item1 OR item2; else SHOW item0
```

Here is a visual:

[/anyRoute, show item0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxDTi.png)

[/route01, show item1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d8GI.png)

[/route02, show item2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ICDP.png)

I am fairly new to all this and I seem to get confused with how to go about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your component

```
import { Routes, Router } from 'node_modules/@angular/router';

export class YourComponent implements OnInit{
     constructor(public router: Router ) {
    }
}
```

In HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="router.url.includes('route01')">
    <p>Item0</p>
</ng-container>
```