# Use *ngIf= for specific router link and all child routes

Tags: angular, routes, wildcard, router

**Problem:** Show [content] in all child routes of parent route ie. `<div *ngIf="router.url === '/parent/child'">[content]</div>` to make it so that ./parent/child1, ./parent/child2, ./parent/child(n), all show [content]

**Proposed solution:** `<div *ngIf="router.url === '/parent/**'">[content]</div>`, or variations `<div *ngIf="router.url === '/parent/..'">[content]</div>`, does not seem to be accepted by the angular framework.

Documentation: https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-wildcard-routes

Based on

Comment: have you tried <div *ngIf="router.url.includes('/parent/')>[content]</div>

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Bumping Fiehra's answer as a proposed solution: use *ngIf="router.url.includes('/parent/) to demarcate child routes referring to the parent. Resolved my problem.

[See more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704530/ngif-with-routing)

Edit: You can also set up a customized service to make sure that you are on the appropriate type of page.